# Blazor Hosted Identity without Areas

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

Out of the box with Blazor WASM Hosted using Identity you get an Area in the Server project for Identity.  When you scaffold the identity views they obviously go into the Identity Area.

I just hate the URL routing for Areas.  Navigating to [url]/identity/account/login and having all account related views within the same url route.   Id prefer to have it just be [URL]/account/login

So my question is 2 fold...

Is there a downside to not using the Identity Area?  Is there a way to configure it to not use Areas and potentially Scaffold the items into the Non Area?

Comment: Do you create Blazor WebAssembly App template and select the ASP.NET Core hosted check box to configure the app to use an ASP.NET Core backend?

Comment: Yes that's the template I am using